# MC Connect and Integrated User requirements for Unsubscribing

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Using MC Connect...when a CRM User clicks the Unsubscribe link on the Page Layout as part of the Managed Package, does that user have to be Integrated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If they are not integrated they will receive a message stating that they need to link their user. I believe that any action that requires an API call and is triggered by the running user requires a linked user - though exactly what is included in this still seems a bit unclear.